# How to know what global variables or static variales are referred by what functions? (C)

Tags: c, gdb, global-variables, lldb, static-variables

I'd like to know what functions refer (read or write) global or static variables in an executable compiled from C.

I don't think gdb or lldb offer such a function out-of-the-box. Is there some other  tool that can do this?

Alternatively, one can get all the global and static variables from gdb/lldb and set a watchpoint on each variable. However, gdb seems not able to allow soft only watchpoint for read as this will require a large number of watchpoints that hardware watchpoints just can not do it. So I'd assume gdb is not appropriate to know what functions refer to what global/static variables.

Is lldb suitable for this task? Is there a ready to use solution for it?

Comment: Your problem might be unsolvable in general. Be aware of [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice's_theorem)

Comment: Just the function itself, directly in its source code, or all the functions the function calls, directly and indirectly, including standard library routines?

Comment: What about something equivalent to `if (false) printf("%d",x);` ? Does that access `x` ? Be aware of the [as-if rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/As-if_rule)

Comment: Just the source code that are compiled excluding system library.

Comment: If at run time, that x should not be considered as accessed. At compile that x should be considered as accessed at syntactic level but unaccessed at semantic level.

Comment: Undex Linux You can known a binary/lib uses a global var (or other thing) not defined in the object/lib through `nm -u | grep thenameyouwant` (managing the fact thenameyouwant is a prefix of course )

Comment: Consider this: Delete any source code after the function. For any source code prior to the function, change any definitions to declarations. Compile the module. Use `nm -u` to see the symbols it refers to. Would that do what you want? If so, why not? (The difference will help clarify your question.)

Comment: There are thousands of functions. I can not delete each function and compile as it will take too much time.

Comment: you can do it by compiling the code with debug information, than using `objdump` (or equivalent) you will be able to view the DWARF (or equivalent) debug information which contain whole lot of who refers to who and in which line, down side is that if you compiled with libraries without debug information then those libraries would not appear in the debug information.

Comment: On Mac objdump is available natively and in binutils. Are you referring to the binutils' objdump? Is Mac's native objdump still appropriate? What options I should use? Thanks.

Comment: If you want a runtime tool: With the Intel pin tool, you can probably write out a trace of all the memory locations accessed along with the pc, then post-process it to get the info you want.

Comment: Doxygen? Cscope? Kscope?

Answer (score 0):

To answer the "Alternatively" part of your question, lldb doesn't support software implemented watchpoints as they don't actually work very well.  So like gdb we are limited to the hardware resources of the machine you are running on.  Unless the globals you want to watch are really big, you should be able to put watchpoints on them one by one, however.

Of course the debugger will only be able to tell you who accessed the watched data in the code that was actually run during the debug session.  So if you want a comprehensive answer for the whole program, the debugger is not the right tool.